# Sublime text: How to do sentence case (capitalize the first letter of a sentence)

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm aware that there is `Edit > Change Case` menu. But there's no option for sentence case.

How do I achieve this? Is this possible for regex to achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this **regex**:

**find**

```
(^|\.\s|…\s)([a-z])
```

**and replace with**

```
\1\u\2
```

Explanation:

1. The first find group (parénthesis group) captures a line beginning or a dot followed by a space or three dots character followed by a space.
2. The second group captures a letter.
3. In the replace expresion *\1* and *\2* refer to the captured groups.
4. *\u* means translate one character to uppercase.
5. This capitalizes lines starting with a character and sentences starting after other sentences.

Comment: (^|\.\s|…\s)([a-z]) can be used to catch "..." character as well.

Answer (score 1):

Find:

```
<h4>(.)(.*)</h4>
```

Replace:

```
<h4>\u\1\L\2</h4>
```

That would make

```
<h4>This Is A Demo</h4>
```

into

```
<h4>This is a demo</h4>
```

Answer (score -2):

It is a possible duplicate of [Sublime Text - command to make first character uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080410/sublime-text-command-to-make-first-character-uppercase).

By the way, in brief, you could use the key-map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>, writing in your "user keybinding file":

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+i"], "command": "title_case" }
```

Comment: "Title Case" is not "Sentence case".

Comment: Select first word of each sentence and make it title case