# Sublime Text - command to make first character uppercase

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, ucfirst

There are `upper_case` and `lower_case` commands:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+u"], "command": "upper_case" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+l"], "command": "lower_case" },
```

I'm searching for command to capitalize the first letter of string, which can be assigned to custom shortcut.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Under **`Edit -> Convert Case`** is the `Title Case` option. The following key binding should work:

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+t"], "command": "title_case" }
```

Add this to your custom keymap, and it will override the default command for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> - `fold_tag_attributes`. Alternatively, you can use

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+i"], "command": "title_case" }
```

which is not assigned to anything in the default Sublime keymap.

If you're interested in other types of conversions, check out the [`Case Conversion`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Case%20Conversion) plugin on Package Control. It installs commands for `snake_case`, `camelCase`, `PascalCase`, `dot.case`, and `dash-case`, along with a few other utilities, such as a function to separate words with slashes.

Comment: If anyone who stumbles upon this is using a OS X. You'll want to paste
`{ "keys": ["super+k", "super+t"], "command": "title_case" }`

Comment: ...but "First character uppercase" isn't the same thing as "Title Case" and this answer only provides the later.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is for Title case but the OP asked for sentence case for what I can gather.

Here's the regex for all *cases* ‍♂️

In sublime press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the replace dialog and click the regex button.

In the find box use: `(^|\.\s+|…\s|\t)([a-z])`

In the replace box use: `\L\1\U\2`

---

Additionally, you can use a plugin called RegReplace found here: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/regreplace so that you can add this to a menu, command or context menu.

I've added all the basic case examples here just to show how to nest the RegReplace items in a sub-menu for your context click menu.

Once installed go to: **Perferences>Package Settings>RegReplace>Rules - User** and paste the following.

```
{
  "format": "3.0",
  "replacements": {

    "case_lower":
    {
      "find": "(.+)",
      "replace": "\\L\\1",
      "greedy": true,
    },

    "case_sentence":
    {
     "find": "(^|\\.\\s+|…\\s|\\t)([a-z])",
     "replace": "\\L\\1\\C\\2",
     "greedy": true
   },

   "case_title":
   {
    "find": "\\b(\\w)(\\w+)",
    "replace": "\\C\\1\\L\\2",
    "greedy": true,
  },

  "case_upper":
  {
    "find": "(.+)",
    "replace": "\\C\\1",
    "greedy": true,
  }

}
}
```

Then go to the menu again and go to: **Perferences>Package Settings>RegReplace>Settings** and paste the following in the user file that'll appear on the right panel.

```
{

 "selection_only": true, // Optional but I prefer to only replace the selection.

 "extended_back_references": true // true allows the \l\1 to return the text to lowercase or others.

}
```

And set up this as a menu go to the file: **...\User\Context.sublime-menu** and paste this:

```
[
  {"caption" : "-"},

  // https://packagecontrol.io/packages/regreplace
  {
    "caption": "Reg Replace",
    "children":
    [
      { "caption": "Convert Case: Lower", "command": "reg_replace", "args": {"replacements": ["case_lower"]} },
      { "caption": "Convert Case: Sentence", "command": "reg_replace", "args": {"replacements": ["case_sentence"]} },
      { "caption": "Convert Case: Title", "command": "reg_replace", "args": {"replacements": ["case_title"]} },
      { "caption": "Convert Case: Upper", "command": "reg_replace", "args": {"replacements": ["case_upper"]} }
    ]

  }

]
```

More RegReplace examples can be found here: **Perferences>Package Settings>RegReplace>Rules - Example**.

### Here's my context-menu

[image: the context menu]

Comment: thanks for the "extended_back_references": true information, it was driving me mad. One thing though, I had to use \L\1, using \\L\\1 did not work correctly for me. Maybe a problem in my end.

Comment: using this method changes the \1 group to lowercase in subsequent uses of the group, so it does not work as expected