# How to use Option+Up and Option+Down change case in Sublime Text

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Sublime Text, I used to be able to hit <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to make text Title case and then hit <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> again to switch it to UPPER case, <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> will do the same in reverse. Now it doesn't seem to have this feature anymore.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Yeah, I remember this functionality and it was really handy.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime has options in the `Edit > Convert Case` menu as well as in the Command Palette under `Convert Case:` to perform these manipulations, but as far as I've aware they've never been bound to those keys by default.  From the sounds of things, you had a plugin or package previously installed that was providing these key bindings for you.

Note also that at least on my Mac, those keys don't trigger any output from `sublime.log_input()` which is an indication that MacOS is handling and consuming them and not passing them on to Sublime, which means that binding a command to those keys wouldn't work unless the OS was told to leave them alone. That could well be down to different versions of OSX, though.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware of the shortcuts you were describing, but in Sublime Text 3, you could use:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>: for upper case

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>: for lower case

And although there's no keyboard shortcuts for Title Case, [you could make one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29081870/7400458).